# Starting the development server... Compiled with warnings. On Windows 10, MERN stack, GIT Bash for Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, git, webpack

My issue goes as follows: I downloaded Git Bash for Windows (which rocks btw), I made a new file called "supertest" to test my MERN stack project... Then I cd'd into that directory and ran the following: `npx create-react-app supertest`. Everything went smoothly until I later realized that I did this procedure in bash and used a lowercase D. "desktop" versus "Desktop".... npm let me do it and the files are all okay... but the `npm start` call is now broken-ish (I tested this and it is totally due to this lowercase "desktop" "Desktop" issue....) How do I fix this? It drives me insane. I can't type shell commands while this is happening, which sucks. 
Here is what it looks like: `MINGW64 ~/desktop/supertest (master)
$ npm start

> supertest@0.1.0 start C:\Users\avasi\desktop\supertest
>   react-scripts start
>   Starting the development server...
>   Compiled with warnings.

(webpack)/buildin/global.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\avasi\Desktop\supertest\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\avasi\Desktop\supertest\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 22 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\avasi\Desktop\supertest\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\avasi\Desktop\supertest\node_modules\sockjs-client\lib\entry.js
* C:\Users\avasi\Desktop\supertest\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\avasi\desktop\supertest\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\avasi\Desktop\supertest\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\avasi\desktop\supertest\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.`

Comment: Also, when I try cd Desktop/supertest (in Git for Windows terminal) it tells me no such directory exists but.... it kindof totally exists...... doesnt it? Sorry total newbie here trying to figure it out. :) Note: I am on a Windows 10 machine... not on mac.

Comment: Do I have to redo the entire init sequence to get this to work? or can I change that spicific directories name to an uppercase D rather than a lowercase? (I will try now) but I am worries it will mess things up. I will post my results here.

Comment: Having a huge problem with this... When I look for the lowercase directory, it shows me it with a lower case "d" name, but when I go to open it, it automatically changes to "D"....... HELP.... This sucks. (For now I am going to just restart the project. Dont want to waste more time with this... Could have implications later.)

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of appending comments.